# Is there a jquery function to list attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Is there a jquery function that can list the attributes an object has? I've trying to use it to see why I'm failing to set the attribute "fill" in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#emitterButton').click(function(){
    $(this).attr({'fill':BUTTON_COLOR_PRESSED});
  });
});
```

. For reference, `#emitterButton` refers to

```
emitterButton = canvas.circle(emitter_center_x,emitter_center_y,BUTTON_RADIUS)
                      .attr({'fill':BUTTON_COLOR_UNPRESSED})
                      .attr({'id':'emitterButton'});
```

, where canvas is a Raphael canvas.

Comment: You can check `$('#emitterButton')[0].attributes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused by two flavors of node-wrapping objects. In your code, `emitterButton` refers to Raphael object - created by `canvas.circle`, having `attr` as a method available to change its state.

But within the event handler, `$(this)` will give you `jQuery` object. By a coincidence, it also has `attr` method - but it only changes the underlying DOM node attribute without triggering the corresponding event.

The solution is to either find the corresponding object again by `id` (with Raphael's [**Paper.getById(id)**](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getById) method):

```
$('#emitterButton').click(function(){
  canvas.getById('emitterButton')
        .attr({'fill':BUTTON_COLOR_PRESSED});
});
```

... or, and sometimes far better, just cache the object:

```
$('#emitterButton').click(function(){
  emitterButton.attr({'fill':BUTTON_COLOR_PRESSED});
});
```

Last, but definitely not the least, you can simply attach click handler to Raphael's object (via [**Element.click()**](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click) method).

---

That solves the actual problem in your code. ) For the completeness' sake, the answer to your original question is simple - if you have a jQuery object stored in `$el`, you can access a list of its attributes with this notation:

```
$el[0].attributes
```

... which, according to [**the docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes), *is a key value pair of strings that represents any information regarding that node*.